# Unexpected use of 'screen' no-restricted-globals reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using reactjs to develop a front end, I want to get the heigth of my screen so I can use `overflowY: scroll`, but when I use `screen.heigth`, an error came out:

> Unexpected use of 'screen'  no-restricted-globals

I also used `window.location.heigth` and nothing happened.

Comment: Do you use ESLint in your project? See here https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals

Comment: Hello Abdel, it would be helpful if you provided the relevant parts of your code. Could you please edit your question to include them? The error message "Unexpected use of 'screen' no-restricted-globals" comes from ESLint, see documentation here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals. You could turn it off by adding a comment `// eslint-disable-next-line`, but that would probably not solve your problem.

Comment: @proti, eslint package is in my node modules directory, so i think i'm using it

Comment: @AbdelJelilZaghouani so that is why you got this error. Without the component code it will be hard to help you.

Answer (score 24):

This eslint rule warns you about using a global variable. There might be an issue with shadowing or you simply forgot to declare. So you have to be explicit and access it starting `window`

```
window.screen.height
```

Assuming you have created your project using CRA. Read this section of [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-global-variables)

Comment: This works on desktop but fails on mobile (Safari, Chrome)

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg What "This"? "This" (eslint rule) is compile time feature.

Comment: Sorry yeah it's not related - `window.screen` doesn't work on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

per the eslint docs https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

in your .eslintrc file you should be able to declare this to avoid that error:

```
  "globals": {
    "screen": true
  },
```

basically telling eslint that the "screen" global is ok to use, or any other global eslint doesnt recognize